# How to foucs a new window (third party without windowName) in selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium

I am submitting search criteria through form to third party URL. I tried to give target="someName". But when i am trying to focus on new window using "sameName" and validating some text there, selenium unable to find that locator or focus on that window. retuning false. please help on this. its urgent.
I also tried storeAllWindowNames or Ids selenium commands, also not working its returning main window ID instead of new open window.

Comment: Can you create a minimal example of web page + selenium code which exposes this error? At the very least, post how you try to locate and switch to the new window.

Answer (score 0):

the idea is in the following. as you try to validate some text in a new window, I do not see any necessity to get window name as you are able to get the xpath or cssselector of the text to be validated using firepath (firebug addon in ffox) and using command

```
    String txt = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//...blablbalba)).getText().trim();
    //or
   String txt = driver.findElement(cssSelecot(html>..blalblabla...)).getText().trim();
    //validation 
   Assert.assertTrue(txt.equals("blablabla"));
```

you can actually validate it.

or if you want to validate something and selenium is not able to cope with it then I recommend you to use js (getText using js):

```
 String cssSelector=....

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\""+cssSelector+"\");");
            stringBuilder.append("return x.text().toString();")       ;


           String res= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
           Assert.assertTrue(res.trim().contains("blablabla....")   );
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if I am using HTML xpath to match any text..it returns false. I am using selenium IDE firefox add-on.

Comment: <form target="_blank" method="get" action="someURL/Search/Results.aspx" name="search_form" id="search_form"> I tried by giving some name into target="windowName" no success

Comment: I set form target attribute to 'windowName' and tried selectWindow(null) also selectWindow(windowName) both not working. please help..

Comment: what about this?
        driver.switchTo().window("search_form")

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

Well, if you have no choice but use it. Here is one solution:
if you have a target with your own name like `target="popup"`, then you only need open the target window before click on the link. Example:

```
[b]store "javascript{selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().open('', 'popup')}", "myWindow"[/b]
```

If you have a `target="_blank"`, you need change the target before open the window.

```
store "javascript{this.page().findElement('link=My link who open the popup with target blank').target='popup'}", "myVar" 
store "javascript{selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().open('', 'popup')}", "myWindow"
```

Then, you click on the link and `selectWindow("popup")`. That is.

Another solution is rewrite the entire A tag and change the `href/target` by a javascript `window.open` but this is a litle more work to do.